# Textbook Recommentation: Discrete Differential Geometry

Tags: geometry, discrete-geometry

are there any good books that provide a good introduction to Discrete Differential Geometry to beginners? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

A quick search turned up *[Digital Geometry Processing with
Discrete Exterior Calculus](http://www.geometry.caltech.edu/pubs/DGPDEC_SIG13.pdf)* and *[Discrete Differential Geometry: An Applied Introduction](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~kmcrane/Projects/DDG/paper.pdf)*, both by Crane.  The content of the two seems to be very similar.